# Socket Programming Scenario Java

Tags: java, sockets

I have the following situation.

```
Assuming there are 3 systems: A,B,C and A is master.
so, B & C connects to the server at A.
if B & C would like to communicate,
```

will the following scenario work?

```
B connects to A, (creating a socket object at both B & A)
A sends socket object to C
```

(C now has the same socket created using B' connection attempt to A)

```
 B and C can communicate with sockets they have.
```

Can this kind of communcation possible,
I know of a way where either B connects to C, or C connects to B, but I don't want that here. (Also, I am not worried about the scale of the system, i.e., too many active sockets in the system)

Comment: Can you ring someone up and send them your telephone? Same situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A socket connects one of your local port to a port of the remote address. And it has a lifecycle, `create, bind, close`. Serializing sockets and sending to other JVM will not work.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot serialize socket instances. It wouldn't work at the JVM level or at the native machine level. What you can do is use your master server as a communication proxy between the two clients, or alternatively, too explicitly connect one client to the other.